# How to loop over images in a directory?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have cats images in a directory.I want to apply data augmentation manually to these images.

My directory is `Downloads/Images/Cats/`.
This directory has images with two types of labels/names:

1. `cat1_001.png`, `cat1_002.png`, ...
2. `cat2_001.png`, `cat2_002.png`, ...

specifying two types of cat images.

So how can I iterate through the images with label 1 only from the directory in python?

Comment: `for f in glob.glob('Downloads/Images/Cats/*001.png'): ...`

Comment: Or maybe `cat1_*.png`, depending exactly what "label 1" is meant to mean. Putting an example in questions is generally helpful when a description might be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import os
directory_in_str = 'Downloads/Images/Cats/'
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)
    
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if(filename.startswith('cat1_') and filename.endswith('.png')):
        print(filename)
        # do your staff here
```

Comment: Instead of testing if cat1_ is in filename, I would test if filename starts with cat1_. We don't know the name convention and this should be more accurate.

Comment: Good point :)  I edited anwser